# How to omit null values in JSON Dictionary using Mantle?

Tags: ios, github-mantle

I have MyModel inheriting from MTLModel (using the GitHub Mantle pod).
MyModel.h

```
#import <Mantle/Mantle.h>
@interface MyModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *UUID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *someProp;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *anotherProp;
@end
```

MyModel.m

```
#import "MyModel.h"
@implementation MyModel
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
        return @{
            @"UUID": @"id",
            @"someProp": @"some_prop",
            @"anotherProp": @"another"
    };
}
}
@end
```

Now I want to send the JSON to the backend using AFNetworking. Before that I convert the model instance to a JSON NSDictionary to use as parameters/body payload within my request.

```
NSDictionary *JSON = [MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionaryFromModel:myModel];
```

But this JSON consists of strange "" Strings for properties of my model that are nil. What i instead want is Mantle to omit these key/value pairs and just spit out a JSON with only the properties that are not nil or NSNull.null, whatever.

Comment: Can you post the full code for MyModel?

Comment: I edited the question. So imagine an API which is not fully RESTful. So when fetching the data of that model, "some_prop" would be not delivered, which results in being nil. When converting this model back into JSON, the property is translated into "some_prop": "<null>" :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a common issue with Mantle and it's called **implicit JSON mapping**.

`MTLJSONAdapter` reads all properties of a model to create a JSON string optionally replacing property names with ones given in `+JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey`.

If you want some properties to be excluded from the JSON representation of your model, map them to `NSNull.null` in your `+JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey`:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
        @"UUID": @"id",
        @"someProp": @"some_prop",
        @"anotherProp": @"another",
        @"myInternalProperty": NSNull.null,
        @"myAnotherInternalProperty": NSNull.null,
    };
}
```

---

The implicit JSON mapping has lately become a noticeable problem, a solution for which is currently being discussed at Mantle's home repository at GitHub.

See issues [#137](https://github.com/github/Mantle/issues/137), [#138](https://github.com/github/Mantle/issues/138), [#143](https://github.com/github/Mantle/issues/143) and the current discussion under **[#149](https://github.com/github/Mantle/issues/149)**.

---

**EDIT:** I clearly misunderstood the question, but now, when I suppose I understand it correctly, the answer is simple.

`MTLJSONAdapter` generates the JSON data using `MTLModel`'s `dictionaryValue` property. If you wish to exclude a property from the JSON itself, you can overwrite that method in your `MYModel`:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue {
    NSMutableDictionary *originalDictionaryValue = [[super dictionaryValue] mutableCopy];

    if (self.aPropertyThatShouldBeExcludedWhenNil == nil) {
        [originalDictionaryValue removeObjectForKey:@"aPropertyThatShouldBeExcludedWhenNil"];
    }

    /* repeat the process for other "hidden" properties */

    return originalDictionaryValue;
}
```

---

**EDIT #2:** Check out the code* for removing all values that are `nil`:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue {
    NSMutableDictionary *modifiedDictionaryValue = [[super dictionaryValue] mutableCopy];

    for (NSString *originalKey in [super dictionaryValue]) {
        if ([self valueForKey:originalKey] == nil) {
            [modifiedDictionaryValue removeObjectForKey:originalKey];
        }
    }

    return [modifiedDictionaryValue copy];
}
```

<sup><sub>`* - code sample suggested by matths.`</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks for that answer. And I'm already aware of this kind of exclusion of some properties from the JSON representation of the model. But this is not a solution for just omitting null values _at runtime_ when they are null, but including them, if they have valid values.

Comment: OK, It seems like i misunderstood the question. I edited my answer and I hope that this time it will fix your issue. ;)

Comment: That sounds interesting and indeed like a solution. I'll try tomorrow morning (CET) in the office from my working machine, and accept the answer when it works.

Comment: ...and what's the status?

Comment: it works. I might edit your answer and add my code for nil checking all of the properties.

Comment: Glad that it's working! I added the code sample for checking all properties, though I improved it a little bit. ;)

Comment: Strangely the EDIT #2 solution is not working for me. The dictionaryValue method appears to never be called. I had to use value transformers for every value that could be null.

Comment: EDIT #2 used to work for me. But now with the latest Mantle it doesn't work. I see something like "Address = "<null>";" instead of nothing. Anyone has an updated solution? thx!

Comment: Yeah, EDIT #2 doesn't work for me either. I dig into **MTLJSONAdapter.m** and found `NSDictionary *dictionaryValue = [model.dictionaryValue dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:propertyKeysToSerialize.allObjects];`. The variable `model.dictionaryValue` has nil-value keys removed correctly but it got inserted back with `- dictionaryWithValuesForKeys`. May be we have to manage the `propertyKeysToSerialize` as well. That's just a clue. I will update if i have a good solution.

Comment: Done, see my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/31110765/467588 . It's probably not the best solution, but it works for me :)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, need to subclass MTLJSONAdapter

Comment: overriding ```- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue error:(NSError **)error;``` did the job for me

Answer (score 2):

I remove nil valued keys by creating an **MTLJSONAdapter subclass**, and overriding `-serializablePropertyKeys:forModel:` method.

*MTLJSONAdapterWithoutNil.h*

```
/** A MTLJSONAdapter subclass that removes model dictionaryValue keys whose value is `[NSNull null]`. */
@interface MTLJSONAdapterWithoutNil : MTLJSONAdapter
@end
```

*MTLJSONAdapterWithoutNil.m*

```
#import "MTLJSONAdapterWithoutNil.h"

@implementation MTLJSONAdapterWithoutNil

- (NSSet *)serializablePropertyKeys:(NSSet *)propertyKeys forModel:(id<MTLJSONSerializing>)model {
    NSMutableSet *ms = propertyKeys.mutableCopy;
    NSDictionary *modelDictValue = [model dictionaryValue];
    for (NSString *key in ms) {
        id val = [modelDictValue valueForKey:key];
        if ([[NSNull null] isEqual:val]) { // MTLModel -dictionaryValue nil value is represented by NSNull
            [ms removeObject:key];
        }
    }
    return [NSSet setWithSet:ms];
}

@end
```

And use this to create JSON dictionary instead. Like this:

`NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [MTLJSONAdapterWithoutNil JSONDictionaryFromModel:collection error:nil];`

**NOTE:** **if you are overriding `NSValueTransformer` methods for array or dictionary properties, you also have to change the `MTLJSONAdapter` class to your subclass as well.** Like this:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)myDailyDataArrayJSONTransformer {
    return [MTLJSONAdapterWithoutNil arrayTransformerWithModelClass:KBDailyData.class];
}
```

Comment: What is the `val` in `[[NSNull null] isEqual:val]`?

Comment: looks like you forgot to say `val = modelDictValue[key]`

Comment: Yes, I forgot that, sorry T_T. Edited.

Comment: Hi @Hlung did you succeed making it working for nested models?

Comment: @SergiiN. I didn't tried that case. Is this solution not working?

Comment: @Hlung it work for top level model, but for its nested models default `MTLJSONAdapter` is still used based on `Mantle` implementation here: https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/blob/master/Mantle/MTLJSONAdapter.m#L106

**UPD:** I invetsigated more and for nested class `NSValueTransformers` are being used based on this method: https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/blob/master/Mantle/MTLJSONAdapter.m#L475

And they are all using creating `MTLJSONAdapter ` instance internally :(

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The iteration should be on `propertyKeys` however, to avoid mutating a collection under iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding - dictionaryValues did not give me the expected behavior

So I created a method for MTL Base class

```
    - (NSDictionary *)nonNullDictionaryWithAdditionalParams:(NSDictionary *)params error:(NSError *)error {
        NSDictionary *allParams = [MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionaryFromModel:self error: &error];
        NSMutableDictionary *modifiedDictionaryValue = [allParams mutableCopy];

        for (NSString *originalKey in allParams) {
            if ([allParams objectForKey:originalKey] == NSNull.null) {
                [modifiedDictionaryValue removeObjectForKey:originalKey];
            }
        }

        [modifiedDictionaryValue addEntriesFromDictionary:params];
        return [modifiedDictionaryValue copy];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The EDIT #2 used to work for me with the previous Mantle code base. Now I have to do the following to continue using EDIT #2:

In file MTLJSONAdapter.m, replace this line:

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryValue = [model.dictionaryValue dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:propertyKeysToSerialize.allObjects];
```

with

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryValue = model.dictionaryValue;
```

The above is my current workaround to get

```
{ }
```

instead of

```
{
  "AddressLine2" : null,
  "City" : null,
  "ZipCode" : null,
  "State" : null,
  "AddressLine1" : null
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you should modify the files in Mantle framework directly.

Comment: That only makes sense if your property names are identical to the JSON key names